# Entity print module. How to create TOC?

Tags: entities, 8

I'm using entity print module and wkhtmltopdf library.
Even though I've checked the create table of contents on the configuration, I don't know how to do that. I've created h1, h2 and h3 but the TOC is nit there. 
So anybody know how to do it?

Also is there any way I can control the pages? I mean, I need to add an image only on the first page, and a footer on the other pages. I know wkhtmltopdf has this feaure, but I don't know how to solve it in drupal

Comment: I haven't used this module, but there is some documentation about stying it: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/entity-print/usage#from-your-theme Just because wkhtmltopdf has a feature doesn't mean that the Drupal module will have it implemented.

Comment: @prkos Yes, I did all the styling on that page. I know that maybe Drupal doesn't have the feature, but on the module configuration it has a checkbox abut the table of contents, so I guess that's a feature Drupal has, but I don't know.